# Updating an entry in PersistentVector not working NEAR Protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to update the status of a job object. I get the "success" message return but the value is not updating. Do I miss something?

```
@nearBindgen
export class Contract {
  private jobs: PersistentVector<Job> = new PersistentVector<Job>('jobs');
```

......

```
@mutateState()
  cancelJob(jobTitle: string): string {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.jobs.length; i++) {
      if (this.jobs[i].title == jobTitle) {
          this.jobs[i].status = "Cancelled";
        return "success"
      }
    }
    return "not found";
  }
```

And I'm calling it like that:

```
near call apptwo.msaudi.testnet cancelJob '{\"jobTitle\":\"title2\"}' --account-id=msaudi.testnet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not enough to update entry when you fetch it. You need to update the storage on the contract as well. Write it back in so to speak.

This isn’t enough

`this.jobs[i].status = "Cancelled";`

You need to add it back in:

```as
if (this.jobs[i].title == jobTitle) {
  const job: Job = this.jobs[i]; // Need an intermediate object in memory
  job.status = "Cancelled";
  this.jobs.replace(i, job); // Update storage with the new job.
  return "success"
}
```

Comment: It seems to have another issue. I tried this :  
this.jobs[0].status = 1;
this.jobs.replace(0, this.jobs[0]); // need to actually update the storage.
 return "changed to ? " + this.jobs[0].status.toString();
It prints 0. It does not change even the variable. Do I miss something?

Comment: I think it does make sense that we can't change data that are already stored in the chain?
I made a workaround by creating a new list and adding the completed jobs to that list.

Comment: @MSaudi I was a bit quick when I made the example. We need to create an intermediate object, make changes to the object, and then replace it. Then you don't need to do the workaround. I have updated my example accordingly